# Unable to connect to the database using Hikari connection pool

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hikaricp

I wish to use Hikari Connection Pool in my Spring application to connect to the Oracle Database

Below is the connection string

> JDBC URL:
> jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldaps://abc-def-dmz.demo.com:876/SOM_APP,cn=oraclecontext,dc=demo,dc=com

Getting the following error

> Error Message: Failed to initialize pool: IO Error: JNDI Package
> failure javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:876[Root
> exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]

How do I fix this?

Comment: For everything but MySQL, [HikariCP recommends using dataSourceClassName](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names) although it also says it's fine to use jdbcUrl. Could you share the configuration you use to make the connection? either java code or application.properties file.

Comment: How do I get the data source classname from the jdbc url?

Comment: Did you check LDAP server has SSL support and is reachable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

The error implies that your connection is being blocked, most likely by a firewall. Check with your DBA and system or network administrators to make sure the network path to the server is open, and that you are using the right port numbers.